# Basic questions about fitting a formula with gradient descent or genetic algorythm

Tags: python, curve-fitting, genetic-algorithm, gradient-descent

I've been trying to code a following problem. I have defined a function depending on a number of parameters (in my case, those of a Bragg mirror and a x-ray beam). Now I am trying to compare the results to those modelled by a different program using the same formula, but it seems some of my parameters are off, so the results [aren't quite the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSd3J.png).

What should I do if I want to figure out the correct parameters? The only things I have are the formula f (x1, x2,..), the experimental curve I am comparing my results to and some idea of what the parameters should look like (x1 +- dx1, x2 +- dx2,..).

What do I use to minimize the residual? I know that [Multifitting](http://xray-optics.org/products/software-multifitting/) uses the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://gist.github.com/geggo/92c77159a9b8db5aae73), and I've read about that being possible with a [genetic algorythm](https://towardsdatascience.com/genetic-algorithm-implementation-in-python-5ab67bb124a6) or stochastic gradient descent (though it is my understanding those are more often used for the tasks with neural networks). I'm having some trouble figuring out what and how should I code: the function takes a couple minutes to compute, so the genetic algorythm may be not ideal, and I admit I'm kind of failing to figure out [the SCG I know to be implemented in Python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html).

What would you suggest for me to use in my simpler case? If there are other algorythms to be implemented here besides the one using the GA module, is there a clear masic explanation of them? Am I asking this question in the right place? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GA or using SGD in anything other than neural networks. But, it looks like when the values of `reflected energy` on the y-axis go below `10^-4` the fitting has a difficult time doing its job. Just a couple of ideas:

1. Looking at what happens at the gradient at values for `y < 10^-4`. Does it disappear when the function plunges? Does it return weird values?
2. Checking out [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) and  [scipy's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) optimizers and fitters if you haven't done so already.
3. Checking if your function returns NaN values when the function plunges or goes down to small y-values.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the points made by sbjartmar, but I suspect there is a simpler explanation of the difference and the route toward fixing the fit you are getting.  I should say that I am not familiar with the Multifitting software but I suspect that it is doing something that you are not and should try too:

Since you are plotting on a log-scale, you are emphasizing the very-low intensity values.  In fact, the fit it pretty good to the high-intensity values and gets progressively worse at low intensities.   This is understandable - a small misfit at high intensity is much more of a contribution to the total misfit than a large misfit at very low intensity.

One good way to overcome this is to ***fit in log space***.  That is, have your model calculate `log(Intensity)` and pass in data for `log(Intensity)`.

This is independent of the method used to solve the problem - it recasts the problem to be solved.  Genetic Algorithms might be useful here, but if Levenberg-Marquardt (which will be much faster) is working as well as you show, it is probably good enough, or at least worth continuing to work with.  GAs are typically better at making sure the solution does not get stuck in a "local minimum".   So far, there's no evidence of that happening (but it is always something to keep in mind).  I think that SGD method you point to is aimed at solving a different class of problems.